# html background image orientation turned right

Tags: html, css

I'm using a function to generate different background images but they seem to be turned right. How do I have them set to their normal orientation? I checked the images and they are all facing the correct way.

html

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%; height: 700px;">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 hidden-sm hidden-xs leftimg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 rightimg">
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.rightimg{
    padding-left:0;
    background-image: url("./images/rightside/pic5.jpg");
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%;
}
```

The image I have doesn't matter. Depending on the resolution of the image, the browser will automatically turn my image 90 degrees for some reason.

Comment: can you post code ?

Comment: My code doesn't really have anything important. I just want to know what I could do to keep the orientation properly facing the correct way. Depending on the image (if it has a larger height), it will turn the image 90 degrees.

Comment: Are your images photos from a mobile? Some of these have orientation metadata which is variously understood or misunderstood by different browsers. Does your problem persist in all browsers?

Comment: Now that I think about it, there are some images from instagram. This problem occurs in firefox and chrome. How would you recommend I fix them?

Comment: Look into translate CSS or you may need to use a EXIF reader to fix the orientation using canvas

Answer (score -1):

use background-position for change oritation.

Comment: Hey, there! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you maybe be more specific on your answer? That is, how exactly can OP use `background-position` to change the image orientation? Could you provide some example code? Thanks!